# Just now I upgrade from Ubuntu 13.10 to Lubuntu 16.10 from a live USB, how to retrieve my home folder's files before upgrade?

Tags: upgrade, lubuntu, home-directory

Clearly on the **installer** says that it will keep my files and only the setting will be cleared if I proceed the **installation**, and now the files are gone.

But, I find my old user folder inside `/media/` but I can't navigate to or look in it.

Comment: That sounds like an issue with file permissions. Can you do `ls -l /media` to see what the permissions are? And perhaps `sudo ls /media` and `sudo cp -r /media new_location` to list and copy the files as the root user (who is allowed to do anything)?

Comment: You cannot skip releases while upgrading, this applies too upgrading via the Ubuntu ISO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot skip releases while upgrading, this also applies too upgrading via the Ubuntu ISO.

This means that, unless you had a **separate** `/home` partition, Ubuntu 16.10 was installed over 13.10 **withouth** preserving any previous files.

If you want to recover any important files stop using your computer, turn it off your computer right now and use an Ubuntu or any other Linux live ISO and try to recover your files with [TestDisk](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3883/how-to-recover-deleted-files)